# Jenkinsfile - JsonSlurper returning a string instead of a map

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

So I'm trying out a CI build that has a config.json file embedded.

```
config.json
{
  "some_collection": [
    { "foo": "bar" }
  ]
}
```

My Jenkinsfile:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

node {
  bootstrap()
  test()
}
def bootstrap() {
  stage('bootstrap') {
    git([url: "git@github.com:my-user/my-jenkinsfile-repo.git"])
  }
}

def test() {
  def config = getConfig()
  echo "${config}"
  echo "${config.class}"
}

@NonCPS
def getConfig() {
  new JsonSlurper().parseText(readFile("./config.json")))
}
```

The echo of the config object shows the json as it is in the file, and the config.class says is a plain old string. I'm expecting the code about to return a Map.

I've tried JsonSlurper and JsonSluperClassic, I've also tried about every way I can think of to restructure the code to be more explicit and I'm running out of ideas.

EDIT: I've tried adding some strong typing:

```
def getConfig() {
  JsonSlurper parser = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper()
  def json = readFile("./config.json")
  Map parsedJson = parser.parseText(json)
  return parsedJson
}
```

This still causes config.class to return as a String

Comment: What's this method `readFile`, what does it return? Can you try to replace it with `new File("./config.json").getText()`? And you can specify the exact class that you expect in `getConfig()` declaration by replacing `def` with `Map`.

Comment: The new File variant threw an error about how the file class was not allowed in the context of Jenkins, I will try the Map declaration.

Comment: Can you try to make your `config` object explicitly `Map` too?

Answer (score 5):

Handling JSON in Jenkins with the default libraries is a mess. Just use the `readJSON` step from the Pipeline Utility Steps Plugin.  https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-utility-steps-plugin/blob/master/docs/STEPS.md

Comment: not really sure why you got the downvote(s) but I'll give you +1 since I think this is perfectly valid and relevant.

Comment: `readJSON` is also a mess because of https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-61883

Comment: There is one advantage of readJSON against JsonSlurper and JsonSluperClassic.
readJSON merges duplicated keys and their values if they are present in the json text, as JsonSlurper and JsonSluperClassic overwrite it.

Answer (score 2):

Yyou can use `new File(filename)` to get the content of the `config.json` and pass it to `parse()` method.

You can just use:

```
def getConfig() {
   def pjson = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(new File('./config.json'))
   assert pjson instanceof Map
   pjson
}
```

Comment: `Scripts not permitted to use new java.io.File java.lang.String` unfortunately

Comment: Looks you need to provide permission? Please see [this](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-34638)